# How to add strings to a list created by the readlines() function

Tags: python, string, file, append

I'm trying to append a string to the list returned by the `readlines()` function.

```
 number = str(int(input("Number:")))
 input_name = ((input("Lastname:") + (input("Firstname:")))

 file = "TXT.txt"
 # Open file with default mode for reading
 f = open(file)
 lines = f.readlines()
 # Loop for each line in the file
 for line in lines:
     # The name is the values indexed from 0 (first character) to -4 (fourth to last character)
    name = line[0:-4]
    # Check if name has been appended before
    if name == input_name:
      # If value of name is input_name, concentrate the number onto the line
      found = True
      print("\nYour name has been found in the file.\n")
      new_line = line[:-1] + "," + number + "\n"
      lines.remove(line)
      lines.append(new_line)
      # Break the loop
      break
   # Otherwise, continue the loop
   else:
       found = False
f.close()

if found == False:
   with open(file, "a") as f:
     f.write(name + "," + number + "\n")
```

else:
      with open(file, "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
          f.write(line)

When I test it, if the name has already been dumped into the file, it works.
However when I run the module a second time, the number appended to the list is deleted and is replaced with the new number instead.

E.G.

If I input the name Gerald Tim and the program finds the name in the file, 
the first time I run it the number will be added to the name, but the second time I run it it deletes the other number replaces it with the new input
number.

I would like the program not to delete the last number input.

Comment: what are you using `found` for? Your loop breaks `if name == input_name`

Comment: Doesn't `readlines()` return a generator?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen, no it returns a list

Comment: Also you might find using a dict to be a good approach

Comment: Could you give an example of input and output expectations. I do not think we fully understand the problem. I am guessing that you are re-running the outputted file, and searching for the same name and expecting that it will not replace the already replaced name? so you want to search for the same name more than once and have it appended with a different number more than once? sample in and out would be useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be modifying the list you are iterating over. Try iterating over a copy and modifying the original. Also, you are not actually writing the new line back to the file. Try this:

```
 number = str(int(input("Number:")))
 input_name = ((input("Lastname:") + (input("Firstname:")))

 file = "TXT.txt"

 # Open file with default mode for reading
 f = open(file)
 lines = f.readlines()
 f.close()  # close the file sooner rather than later.

 # Loop for each line in the file
 for line in list(lines):  # <-- Create a copy to iterate over
     # The name is the values indexed from 0 (first character) to -4 (fourth to last character)
    name = line[0:-4]
    # Check if name has been appended before
    if name == input_name:
      # If value of name is input_name, concentrate the number onto the line
      found = True
      print("\nYour name has been found in the file.\n")
      new_line = line[:-1] + "," + number + "\n"
      lines.remove(line)
      lines.append(new_line)
      # Break the loop
      break
   # Otherwise, continue the loop
   else:
       found = False

 # Overwrite the file with the updated data.
 with open(file, 'w') as myfile:
     myfile.writelines(lines)
```

The `readlines` method just gives a list of the lines read from the file - modifying it does not modify the file. Once you have a modified list, overwrite the file. Now the number should be there on the second run.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While not a good idea, it is not an issue as the OP only removes a single item then breaking

Comment: Good point. Thanks. I think I realized later what they were actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

A bit simplified and legible (pythonic). This will look for the name based on your criteria and append the result to the array as specified in your script above.

```
number = str(int(input("Number:")))
input_name = ((input("Lastname:") + (input("Firstname:")))

file = "TXT.txt"

# initialize result array
res_array = []

# Open file with default mode for reading
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if input_name == line[0:-4]:
            print("\nYour name has been found in the file")
            res_array.append("{0},{1}".format(line[:-1], number))
            break
        else:
            res_array.append(line)

# print out the resulting array
print(res_array)
```

If you need to output to another file then:

number = str(int(input("Number:")))
    input_name = ((input("Lastname:") + (input("Firstname:")))

```
file = "TXT.txt"

# output file
outfile = "outTXT.txt"

# Open file with default mode for reading
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    with open(outfile, 'w') as fo:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if input_name == line[0:-4]:
                print("\nYour name has been found in the file")
                fo.write("{0},{1}\n".format(line[:-1], number))
                break
            else:
                fo.write("{0}\n".format(line))
```

By using the ***with*** keyword, the file will close itself as soon it exits that specific indent.

Comment: Actually its when using the 'with' keyword that the file will automatically close.